# Problem regarding translation googletrans library

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, google-translate, google-translation-api

I am kinda of new in this domain, and i have a couple of questions. But let`s discuss the subject first :D So i got an csv file which i  want to translate. I used the following code

```
pip install contractions
pip install googletrans

import pandas as pd
import os 
import from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/gdrive')
from googletrans import Translator

df = pd.read_csv(os.path.join(path, 'csvfile.csv'))

translator = Translator()
translations = {}
for column in df.columns:      
    unique_elements = df[column].unique()
    for element in unique_elements:       
        translations[element] = translator.translate(element).text

print(translations)
```

So here i recieve the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------

JSONDecodeError                           Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-8-ccacb6d48514> in <module>()
      5     unique_elements = df[column].unique()
      6     for element in unique_elements:
----> 7         translations[element] = translator.translate(element).text
      8 
      9 print(translations)

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/googletrans/client.py in translate(self, text, dest, src)
    170 
    171         origin = text
--> 172         data = self._translate(text, dest, src)
    173 
    174         # this code will be updated when the format is changed.
```

Thank you all !!

Answer (score 0):

try providing src and dest parameters in translate method.

```
from googletrans import Translator
t = Translator()
t.translate(word, src='en', dest='fr').text
```

or you might runout of number of request allowed on a single day. ( nearly 850 request can be made )

Comment: Well my csv has 1000 rows, how can i solve this issue?

Comment: store values of the previously translated results in csv is only solution possible.